# How can I change the position of an item in ListView dynamically in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to change the position of an item in ListView dynamically.How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "change position"? swap item on place 2 with item on place 3 ?

Comment: yes,I want to have a button in my list view so on pressing that button that row should shift to first position in listview.

Comment: Yes,I want to have a button on list row so on pressing that button the row should shift to first position.

Answer (score 5):

The ListView is backed up by some data structure (e.g. a `List<String>`). So you can do

Pseudocode:

```
List<String> list = ...
ListView lv = ..
Adapter a = new Adapter(..., list);
lv.setOnClickListener(this);

onItemPressed(..., int position, ...) {
   tmp = list.get(0);
   list.set(0, list.get(position));
   list.set(position,tmp);
   a.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the following link

This is working fine for me

http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html

https://sites.google.com/site/ericbharlow/sample-code/DragNDrop.zip?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 0):

do this for change position of listview in coding

```
ListView.setSelection(position);
```