# How swap two rows on ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview, swap, items

I have looked for answer on this question and found this one page [How can I change the position of an item in ListView dynamically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828568/how-can-i-change-the-position-of-an-item-in-listview-dynamically-in-android)

but from another source I know that changing of the list of objects don't reflect on `ListView` structure after calling .`notifyDataSetChanged()`. It works only when you use own methods of the adapter like `insert(), remove(), add()`, ... ([notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426))

How can I swap (exchange positions) two ListView items?